# PHP Juggling reading and compare hashes from file

Tags: php, readfile

this relates to a hacking challenge on hackthebox.eu 'grammar': I have populated a text file will hashes to compare, loose comparison within PHP.

```
<?php

$handle = fopen("test-md5", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !==false) {
            $targethash = $line;
            if ($targethash == 'ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d') {
            echo "\n---yes, these match"; exit(0);
        }
        else {print "   "; print "ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d !== ".$targethash;}
    }
    fclose($handle);
    echo "\nTesting Complete\n";

} else {
    // error opening the file.
    echo "error";
}
```

My text file contains in one-line the same md5 hash that is in the main code but it does not compare as true in the output:

```
ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d !== B73C2D22763D1CE2143A3755C1D0AD3A
   ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d !== 3DB1A73A245AA55C61204C56C8D99F6D
   ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d !== ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d

Testing Complete
```

I am new to coding, but grew this script from a simple testing script below:

```
<?php
if (('ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d')
    ==
    ('ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d'))
    {  print "Yes, these are the same values.\n";}

        else {print "no match\n" ;}


?>
```

Having retyped the code in Netbeans-IDE, I could not see any syntax errors but can't seem to figure out why its not finding the same hash in the text file.
Thanks

Comment: Probably each line ends with a linebreak. Apply `trim` before comparison.

Comment: Modified:
$targethash = trim($line);

And result is a match at the correct value - perfect

Comment: You can __answer__ your question. There's no need to write unreadable comments.

Answer (score 0):

From u_mulder post to use the function trim() the updated code is:

```
    <?php
    $handle = fopen("test-md5", "r");
    if ($handle) {
        while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            $targethash = trim($line);
            $target = (int)$targethash;
            if ( $target == "ff6d0a568d61e5a03bcdb04509d5885d" ) {
               print "-----Yes, these are the same values.-"."      ".$targethash."\n";
            }
            else {print "not a match   "; print $line;}
        }

        fclose($handle);
        echo "\nTesting complete\n";
} else {
    // error opening the file.
    echo "error";
}

?>
```

After the 'trim' fixed it to compare each line it read form a list of md5 hashes, it needed the received hash to be read as a number to trigger the loose comparison. A similar type change must be used in the MAC to finish the challenge on HTB to trigger the loose comparison weakness in the authorisation cookie.